# undefined method `image' for #<Array> when using group_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi can anyone point me to the right direction? I´m trying to show images on `views/pages/index.html.erb` the images are uploaded on `views/products/new.html.erb`through the `_form.html.erb`partial. Each product/picture then belongs to a category which I can select in the `_navbar.html.erb` and is then directed to the `views/categories/show.html.erb`to see pictures of each product in that category and so on.

That is all working fine

But now I want to display the last added picture in each category on the `views/pages/index.html.erb` and I´m always getting this error : `undefined method 'image' for #<Array:0x007f8d1fb19ff0>`

I´m pretty lost at the moment, and hopefully someone can guide me to the right path.

My code id like this:

pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @products = Product.all.order(created_at: :desc).group_by(&:category_id)
  end

  def about
  end

  def location
  end

  def stockists
  end
end
```

views/pages/index.html.erb

```
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 center-block " >
            <%= image_tag product.image.url(:medium) %>
            <p><%= product.name %></p>
            <p><%= product.category.name %></p>
        <% end %>
        </div>
```

And then I have, the products.rb and category.rb

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

    validates_presence_of :name, :price
    validates_numericality_of :price

    belongs_to :category
end
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :products

end
```

this as part of the schema.rb

```
  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.float    "price"
    t.string   "image"
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
    t.integer  "category_id", default: 1
  end

  add_index "products", ["category_id"], name: "index_products_on_category_id", using: :btree
```

and in the end there is this part

```
 add_foreign_key "order_items", "orders", on_delete: :cascade
 add_foreign_key "order_items", "products"
 add_foreign_key "orders", "users", on_delete: :cascade
 add_foreign_key "products", "categories"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `group_by` in the controller, an enumerable method that **returns a hash** of `Product` arrays keyed by `category_id`.

```
@product = {
  :category1 => [#<Product category_id=1>, #<Product category_id=1>, ...],
  :category2 => [#<Product category_id=2>, #<Product category_id=2>, ...]
}
```

When you loop through `@products` in the view, **you are looping through a hash** where each iteration is **passing an array**.

The `product` variable does not contain a product, but an array of products.

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>             # product is type Array!
  <%= image_tag product.image.url(:medium) %> # Array.image throws an error! 
<% end %>
```

You must create an outer loop to step through the hash.

```
<% @products.each do |category, products| %>
  <% products.each do |product| %>
    # do stuff       
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it is very informative. But it throws back this error `undefined method 'image' for 3:Fixnum` when I add it to my code

Comment: Thank you @Substantial , this works fine now, I can see All products from every category.....Do you mind if I ask,  How would I change this code so I could only see 1 picture from each category on the index page?

Comment: Change the product loop to `<% products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>` then check whether `index == 0` before including a picture.

Comment: It works like wonder, thank you @Subsantial, You are a legend and a hero :)